# Using read() and write() system calls

Tags: c, io

So I have an assignment where I'm supposed to use read and write to read in lines from a file from stdin, sort it, then write it out to stdout with write. However, I can't get it to work.

I have to call a sort function on buf first to sort the string (which I got using read) before I re-output it. Can I treat buf as an array? Or does it not work like that? The reason is because I have to sort the string first.

```
int record_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return (memcmp(a, b, num_bytes));
}
 qsort(buf, num_elements, num_bytes, record_compare);
 while (count < n - num_bytes)
 {
   i = memcmp(buf+count, buf+count + num_bytes, num_bytes);
   if (i == 0)
     count = count + num_bytes;
   else
   {
     for (k = 0; k < num_bytes; k++)
     {
   printf("%c", buf[count]);
   count++;
     }
   }     
 }
```

But since I got the string with read instead of something like fgets, can I still treat buf as an array? This is how the sort works on a normal array (it sorts it then prints out without repeats.

```
 do {
     c = read(0, buf+n, 1);
     if (c != 0)
        n++;
   }
 while (c != 0);
```

This is how I got buf.

Answer (score 2):

The `read()` system call will read N bytes (1 byte at a time the way you've written the code).  You will want to read up until you get a newline, or until you get zero bytes returned (which marks EOF), or until you get an error. Assuming you found a newline, you will start a new buffer.

You'll probably have an array of character pointers, and you'll probably allocate a new string for each line, and store the pointer in the array of character pointers.

```
enum { MAX_LINES = 1024 };
char *lines[MAX_LINES];
int n_lines = 0;
```

I'm assuming a fixed upper bound is OK; you could arrange to dynamically allocate the array of pointers too.

So, you'll need a function to read a line and store it.

Then you have a problem with your compare function.  You'll be calling:

```
qsort(lines, n_lines, sizeof(char *), record_compare);
```

But `record_compare()` will be given two `char **` values, so you need to use:

```
int record_compare(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const char *s1 = *(char **)v1;
    const char *s2 = *(char **)v2;
    return(strcmp(s1, s2));
}
```

Writing the sorted data is pretty straight forward.  So, you need to concentrate on the line reader function.